# How to organize my query with so many ANDs

Tags: mysql

My query looks like:

```
 SELECT SUM(ct_product_store_quantity.quantity) as quantity, `ct_product`.* 
FROM `ct_product`
LEFT JOIN `ct_productLang` ON `ct_product`.`id` = `ct_productLang`.`product_id`
LEFT JOIN `ct_product_store_quantity` ON `ct_product`.`id` = `ct_product_store_quantity`.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN `ct_product_attribute` as cpa ON ct_product.id=cpa.product_id 
WHERE cpa.attribute_id=10 
AND cpa.attribute_value_id=36 
AND cpa.attribute_id=2 
AND cpa.attribute_value_id=5 
AND cpa.attribute_id=7 
AND cpa.attribute_value_id=31
AND cpa.attribute_id=9 
AND cpa.attribute_value_id=28
AND cpa.attribute_id=8 
AND cpa.attribute_value_id=25 
GROUP BY `ct_product`.`id`
HAVING quantity > 0 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

In simple words - each of the `AND` condtitions evaluate to `true`. If I execute them one by one it is OK. But when I try to execute it like what I posted above - no results are returned. I am sure am not doing right the multiple `AND` conditions part. The `ct_product_attribute` table:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| attribute_set_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| attribute_id       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| attribute_value_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Will post the other tables if needed. Just trying to not flood the post. Thank you!

**EDIT**
In `ct_product` I got products like ( just for example ):

```
id
 1
 2
 3
```

In `ct_product_attribute` each product can have more than one attribute-attr.value pairs. Some of the pairs are same.( will show only the columns that I need )

```
id product_id attribute_id attribute_value_id
1       1           1               1 
2       2           1               1
3       1           2               1
4       2           3               1
5       3           1               1
6       3           2               1
```

The values that I get from the request are:

```
attribute_id=1
attribute_value_id=1
attribute_id=2
attribute_value_id=1
```

And now I have to retrieve only the product with `id=1`. If I use OR it is retrieving both products `id=1` and `id=2`. Not sure if it gets more clear now.

Comment: What your query is trying to do is to have attribute_id 2 at the same time as it has 7 and 9 and 8 and well - no row will ever match that logic. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to retrieve but this looks like you'll need to utilize OR based logic or possible an IN subquery.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that a column within a single row cannot have multiple values? What do you want to achieve with this query?

Comment: You're running `cpa.attribute_id=10` on one line, and then two lines later running `AND cpa.attribute_id=2`. This is a shortened version of what you're essentially trying to do: `cpa.attribute_id=10 AND cpa.attribute_id=2` This will always return false, because a column can't be two values at once.

Comment: Are you getting any results from this query ? You are basically asking a single field to have multiple values simultaneously, which is not possible

Comment: Well no result. I am understanding the problem now. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to use ORs amongst your ANDs eg WHERE (cpa.attribute_id=10 
AND cpa.attribute_value_id=36) OR (cpa.attribute_id=2 
AND cpa.attribute_value_id=5)

Comment: I want to retrieve the product from the `ct_produc` table which have all the maches in `ct_product_attribute` table. I think OR conditions will return more than one row. But I need particular one. Will try to update the post with the expected result.

Comment: Just to add to the noise: there is no point in outer joining to ct_product_store_quantity and ct_product_attribute because you are applying predicates against columns in ct_product_attribute (without specifying "or x is null"), thereby removing any rows in ct_product that do not have rows in ct_product_attribute.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure those are supposed to be ORs because you can't have all those IDs at the same time. With that in mind, you should be able to use IN.

```
WHERE cpa.attribute_id IN (10,2,7,9,8) 
AND cpa.attribute_value_id IN (36,5,31,28,25)
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know what you are trying to accomplish but you should/could use WHERE IN, as everyone pointed in the comments you are looking for a field with multiple values...

But, as for the AND question, you could/should use `IN`, as in;

```
 SELECT SUM(ct_product_store_quantity.quantity) as quantity, `ct_product`.* 
FROM `ct_product`
LEFT JOIN `ct_productLang` ON `ct_product`.`id` = `ct_productLang`.`product_id`
LEFT JOIN `ct_product_store_quantity` ON `ct_product`.`id` = `ct_product_store_quantity`.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN `ct_product_attribute` as cpa ON ct_product.id=cpa.product_id 
WHERE cpa.attribute_id IN (10, 2, 7, 9, 8)
AND cpa.attribute_value_id IN (36, 5, 31, 28, 25)
GROUP BY `ct_product`.`id`
HAVING quantity > 0 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `(cpa.attribute_id,cpa.attribute_value_id) in ((10,36),(2,5),(7,31),(9,28),(8,25))`

```
SELECT SUM(ct_product_store_quantity.quantity) as quantity, `ct_product`.* 
FROM `ct_product`
LEFT JOIN `ct_productLang` ON `ct_product`.`id` = `ct_productLang`.`product_id`
LEFT JOIN `ct_product_store_quantity` ON `ct_product`.`id` = `ct_product_store_quantity`.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN `ct_product_attribute` as cpa ON ct_product.id=cpa.product_id 
WHERE (cpa.attribute_id,cpa.attribute_value_id) in ((10,36),(2,5),(7,31),(9,28),(8,25)) and `ct_product`.`id`=1
GROUP BY `ct_product`.`id`
HAVING quantity > 0 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: I have updated the question with what I am trying to achieve. Hope it gets little more clear now.

Comment: @TomaTomov, updated my answer - you can check - you need to specify `ct_product`.`id`=1 in where clause

Comment: That is the problem. I don't know the ID. I need to retrieve it. Guess I am in some total mess. Maybe you are right with OR and IN conditions. Seems my logic is pretty wrong :/